# javascript: function of a div in another div having another function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a nested div.
The child div is inside the parent div.
How can I distinguish the correct onClick function?

In this case, only the function of parent div is called no matter clicking where I click on the nested div.

```
<div class="portfo" onclick="showValue()">
    <div id="cross" onclick="deleteValue()">
         <img src='cross.png' height='15px' width='15px' alt='some'>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, `showValue` is always called whenever I click on the children div.

Comment: What is the problem? That `deleteValue` is not called or that `showValue` is always called?

Comment: It would be helpful if we see your JS.

Answer (score 0):

delete is a reserved word. Try renaming that function to something else. Then both events should fire when click on the image. First the delete event and then the showval one

Answer (score 0):

I think a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) can help you out here. Take a look at the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has to do with [Event Propogation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). This should help you solve it: [Prevent event propogation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Also, `delete()` is a predefined function in JavaScript, you should rename it to something else, unless you're trying to use the built-in function, in that case, please look at the proper usage: [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)